# Как смапить таблицы в hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, java, mysql

Пытаюсь модифицировать petclinic. Создано 3 таблицы в БД. Это

- Lessons(id,name,teacher,description)
- Students(id,first_name,last_name,birthday,faculty)
- Group(id_student,id_lesson)

Вот кусок **.hbm.xml

```
<class name="org.springframework.samples.petclinic.Students" table="students">
<id name="id" column="id">
    <generator class="increment" />
</id>
<property name="first_name" type="java.lang.String" not-null="true" />
<property name="last_name" type="java.lang.String" not-null="true" />
<property name="birthday" type="java.util.Date" column="birthday" />
<property name="faculty" type="int" />
<set name="lessonsInternal" table="group">
    <key column="student_id" />
    <many-to-many column="lesson_id" class="org.springframework.samples.petclinic.Lessons" />
</set>
```

</class>
<class name="org.springframework.samples.petclinic.Lessons" table="lessons">
    <id name="id" column="id">
        <generator class="increment" />
    </id>
    <property name="name" type="java.lang.String" not-null="true" />
    <property name="teacher" type="java.lang.String" not-null="true" />
    <property name="description" type="java.lang.String" not-null="true" />
</class>

Бины:

```
public class BaseEntity {

    private Integer id;

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public boolean isNew() {
        return (this.id == null);
    }

}

package org.springframework.samples.petclinic;

import java.util.Date;

public class Students extends BaseEntity {
    private String first_name;
    private String last_name;
    private Date birthday;
    private int faculty;
    private boolean changed;

    public String getFirst_name() {
        return first_name;
    }

    public void setFirst_name(String first_name) {
        this.first_name = first_name;
    }

    public String getLast_name() {
        return last_name;
    }

    public void setLast_name(String last_name) {
        this.last_name = last_name;
    }

    public Date getBirthday() {
        return birthday;
    }

    public void setBirthday(Date birthday) {
        this.birthday = birthday;
    }

    public int getFaculty() {
        return faculty;
    }

    public void setFaculty(int facult) {
        this.faculty = facult;
    }

    public boolean isChanged() {
        return changed;
    }

    public void setChanged(boolean changed) {
        this.changed = changed;
    }

}

package org.springframework.samples.petclinic;

public class Lessons extends BaseEntity {
    private String name;
    private String teacher;
    private String description;
    private boolean changed;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getTeacher() {
        return teacher;
    }

    public void setTeacher(String teacher) {
        this.teacher = teacher;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public boolean isChanged() {
        return changed;
    }

    public void setChanged(boolean changed) {
        this.changed = changed;
    }
}
```

Запрос

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public Collection<Students> getStudents(){
    return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from students").list();
}
```

Ошибка

```
org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: students is not mapped [from students order by first_name] at org.hibernate.hql.ast.util.SessionFactoryHelper.requireClassPersister(SessionFactoryHelper.java:181) at org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.FromElementFactory.addFromElement(FromElementFactory.java:110) at org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.FromClause.addFromElement(FromClause.java:94) at org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker.createFromElement(HqlSqlWalker.java:316) at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3228) at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElementList(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3112) at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:720) at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:571) at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:288) at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:231) at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:254) at
```

Так как нужно изучить в краткие строки. Не могу все разобрать по полочкам, потому и тут спрашиваю. Если сам бы ковырял эту штуковину то на это ушло бы несколько дней. Прошу отнестись с понимаем.

Comment: @smail2133, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: Я б посоветовал делать на аннотациях. Не плохой пример как это сделать есть на [хабре][1]


  [1]: http://habrahabr.ru/post/132385/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: students is not mapped [from students order by first_name]

Хиб не может найти маппинг для класса `students`, очевидно, потому что ваш класс называется `Students` (с большой буквы). Дело в том что в HQL-запросах используются не имена столбцов и таблиц в БД, а ваши бины и их поля.